# What type of grammar is font-ils?

Tags: verbes

I don't know how one calls this "thing", but want to know the name, so I can look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est le verbe [faire](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/faire.php) conjugué au présent de l'indicatif, 3ème personne du pluriel à la forme interrogative.

- je fais
- tu fais
- il/elle fait
- nous faisons
- vous faites
- **ils/elles font**

Ce qui donne à la forme interrogative :

- fais-je ?
- fais-tu ?
- fait-il/elle ?
- faisons-nous ?
- faites-vous ?
- **font-ils/elles ?**

On appelle cette opération *l'inversion*.

Comment: Pas nécessairement une forme interrogative. C'est un cas général d'inversion du sujet que l'on peut aussi rencontrer ailleurs. Dans les incises par exemple... dis-je. ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt: Effectivement, mais je pense que le contenu de la question appelle une réponse basique ;-)